# Is there a way to rotate myself?

Tags: starmade

I am having trouble in Starmade. I am currentlty building a base, and I want to rotate my character so that his feet are on the floor. The base is oriented correctly, I checked that through the build module.

I know X and Z are used to rotate the ships while in flight, but they don't work when I'm not in the ship. Is there a way to rotate my character? Did I overlook something?

Thanks!

Comment: Do a barrel roll, or try a summersault. :P

Answer (score 1):

Hit space on one of its blocks to align yourself. You can do this to any rotatable structure.